# How to fetch all the running app services on my device using xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to create a xamarin app that is able to fetch all the running app services on my device, and then force stop these apps by clicking on a certain button. Any ideas how?

Comment: You want to write an app that will be able to close other apps?

Comment: write an app that fetch the recent  running app services then closing them , its like phone boosting ..

Comment: iOS absolutely prohibits this.  You may be able to do it on Android under specific conditions.

Comment: We want tp do it using android .. what are these specific condotions??

Comment: If it’s an Android specific question then tag it correctly.  XF is primarily a UI framework and has nothing to do with this